# Get old MySQL data from old mysql folder and import into new database

Tags: php, mysql, windows, phpmyadmin

On my older computer's HDD, I have WAMP5 installed with MySQL and PHPMyAdmin. The data is in the folder. How do I get that data that is in three files? The data is at `E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data\fbdb`, I can see it.

I want to import the `country` table to the `fbdb` database, these are the files I have from it: `country.MYD`, `country.frm` and `country.MYI`

What do I do with these files to add to new database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've created an 'fbdb' database on the new computer, just copy the country.* files you've found into the 'fbdb' folder under your new machine's MySQL data directory, and restart the MySQL server -- as long as it's the same version or newer as the MySQL server on which the table was created, this should be all you need to do, as the MySQL engine will automatically check, and if necessary update, the 'country' table from those files.

Answer (score 1):

You should export and then import the desired parts of your database from your old disk to your new disk, or even the whole database. First you export what you need into a file then you can use that file to import it into the database. Read this forum thread [for more](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=22880) information.